# Android studio wont create new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently upgraded my AS to 2.1.2, my Gradle(manually) to 2.10, and my Gradle plugin to 2.1.0, but when i try to create a new project, AS hangs saying 'Building x Gradle project info'. All the related posts had to do with downloading Gradle, but i already have it downloaded, and made sure my configuration pointed to the right location.

This is where it hangs:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i looked in the Android Studio folder under c:/Program Files, i found another gradle folder with the same distribution(2.10), so i deleted the entire .gradle folder under c:/Users/, which was the one AS was initially pointing to, restarted AS, created a new project, and it built successfully. Once it build i checked the gradle settings and saw it automatically pointed to the Gradle distribution that came with AS. So long story cut short:

-delete C:/Users//.gradle

-restart AS, create a new project, and let it use the bundled distribution under C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle

EDIT: This is not a definite solution, its just what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Vernon, you have to copy (or symlink) your SDK directory into /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk
I feel like I've tried to set the SDK path in preferences to no avail...

in my case:

ln -s /Users/ngonex/android-sdk /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk